# Is it possible to have such kind of slider in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, slider

[image]Please check screen shot. Is such kind of slider is available in Magento 2?

Answer (score 0):

They are NOT part of the core. You won't see slider on default luma theme. Usually most of the 3rd party themes have slider function for the user to insert sliders on frontpage or any parts of the page. If you want to have one WITHOUT installing any 3rd party themes, you can check out extensions like [Banner Slider](https://marketplace.magento.com/magestore-bannerslider-magento2.html) on Marketplace.